# Is it possible to create a common JMS listener for both IBM MQ and ActiveMQ Artemis?

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

I have created a Maven module with all configuration for ActiveMQ Artemis. I have done the same for IBM MQ.

I am building two separate jars for above modules.

Now I have added both jars to the classpath of my microservice.

I am struggling to find a way to load one of the above jar file based on some configuration such as active.broker = artemis or ibm mq.

Answer (score 0):

Given that both ActiveMQ Artemis and IBM MQ provide JMS client implementations it should be relatively straight-forward to use the same JMS application with either.

Both ActiveMQ Artemis and IBM MQ JMS clients include JNDI implementations which can be used to "lookup" their respective admin objects (e.g. connection factories & destinations) in a standard way. You only need to swap the `InitialContext` configuration parameters when using ActiveMQ Artemis vs. IBM MQ.